# how to redirect with htaccess without changing the URL in browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have a normal dynamic url and i want it to make SEO friendly as below

my URL is

```
domain.com/search.php?v1=mobiles&v2=nokia
```

to

```
domain.com/search/mobiles/nokia
```

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use .htaccess file to do this rewriting action without chenging the url in browser,
Try the below code

```
RewriteEngine On  #remove this if already added
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    search.php?s1=$1&s2=$2    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
RewriteEngine On  #if not already on. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #only if it is not calling a file that actually exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #only if it is not calling a directory that actually exists.
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)(/*)([a-z0-9]*)(/*)([a-z0-9]*)(/*) search.php?v1=$1&v2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will work even if you only go to /mobile/ (assuming your search.php can handle that.)

HTH